# Strange performance issues of Java VM

Tags: java, performance

Look please at this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = new String[10000000];
    Arrays.fill(array, "Test");
    long startNoSize;
    long finishNoSize;
    long startSize;
    long finishSize;
    for (int called = 0; called < 6; called++) {
        startNoSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = String.valueOf(i);
        }
        finishNoSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println(finishNoSize - startNoSize);
    }
    System.out.println("Length saved");
    int length = array.length;
    for (int called = 0; called < 6; called++) {
        startSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = String.valueOf(i);
        }
        finishSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println(finishSize - startSize);
    }
}
```

The execution result differs from run to run, but there can be observed a strange behavior:

```
6510
4604
8805
6070
5128
8961
Length saved
6117
5194
8814
6380
8893
3982
```

Generally, there are 3 result: **6 seconds**, **4 seconds**, **8 seconds** and they iterates in the same order.

Who knows, why does it happen?

**UPDATE**

After some playing with -Xms and -Xmx Java VM option the next results was observed:

The minimum total memory size should be at least 1024m for this code, otherwise there will be an OutOfMemoryError. The -Xms option influences the time of execution of `for` block:

It flows between **10 seconds** for -Xms16m and **4 seconds** for -Xms256m.

The question is - why the initial available memory size affect each iteration and not only the first one ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try your program with different heap sizes, and watch the numbers vary in a different pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ingo ! Could you please look at the updated question ?

Comment: as others have told: it is unpredictable when the GC will kick in - but the higher the memory available, the more chances are it does nothing at all for a small test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not entirely unexpected. There are all sorts of factors that could be affecting your numbers.

See: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Micro benchmarking in Java is not that trivial. A lot of things happen in the background when we run a java program; Garbage collection being a prime example. There also might be the case of a context switch from your Java process to another process. IMO, there is no definite explanation why there is a sequence in the seemingly random times generated.